# Passing Powershell Get-ChildItem filter parameter through a string variable is not working

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, get-childitem

In my script I have below function that returns a string as "*.csproj", "*.vbproj", "*.sln". Assuming I always pass a string such as "csproj, vbproj, sln" to $filter parameter:

```
Function Create-Filter($filter)
{    
    $str = $filter.Split(',') | ForEach-Object {"""*.$($_.Trim())"""}

    $str = $str -join ', '
    [string]$str
    return
}
```

Later in my script I perform:

```
$filter = Create-Filter($filter)
$myFiles = Get-ChildItem $source -Include $filter -Recurse
```

But $myFiles is empty, Get-ChildItem is not returning anything. I know that the problem is in $filter parameter when passing to Get-ChildItem but I do not know how to solve this.

Anyway, from powershell console, If i do below It works:

```
PS > $filter = "*.csproj", "*.vbproj", "*.sln"
PS > Get-ChildItem "D:\Path\To\My\Root\Folder" -Include $filter -Recurse
```

So what am I doing wrong?

My powershell version is as below image shows:

[image]

**UPDATE (SOLUTION)**:
Solution proposed by AdminOfThings works.
In my case applying AdminOfThings was not working because I did a mistake in my code. I was assigning the value returned by Create-Filter function into the same variable as that I was passing as argument, like below:

```
$filter = Create-Filter ($filter)
Get-ChildItem "D:\Path\To\My\Root\Folder" -Include $filter -Recurse
```

In order to make it work I have done below:

```
$formattedfilter = Create-Filter ($filter)
Get-ChildItem "D:\Path\To\My\Root\Folder" -Include $formattedfilter -Recurse
```

...that is, using a different variable to assign returned value by function instead of using the same as that I was passing as argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you need to remove the literal quotes (replace triple double quotes with single double quotes), the `-Join`, and the string casting (`[string]`) from your function. Basically, anything that stringifies your output, needs to be removed.

```
Function Create-Filter($filter)
{    
    $filter.Split(',') | ForEach-Object {"*.$($_.Trim())"}
    return
}
```

The `-Include` parameter accepts a single string or an array of strings. When you pass `-Include "string1","string2"`, you are passing an array of strings into the command. In your filter, you are creating one string that includes literal quotes and commas. The subtlety here is including the commas within the quotes creates a string that contains quotes whereas quotes ***BETWEEN*** commas creates a comma separated list of strings. So effectively, the command is reading `-Include '"string1","string2"'`, which will find nothing. Even though your function outputs text that looks identical to what you would type directly into the command, PowerShell will interpret those values differently.

You can see the behavior below where the output of your function is interpreted by PowerShell as a single string.

```
create-filter ("txt","csv")
"*.txt", "*.csv"
(create-filter ("txt","csv")).gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

The array syntax (comma separated list of string types) below outputs a different result.

```
"*.txt","*.csv"
*.txt
*.csv
("*.txt","*.csv").gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

**Executing the Code:**

```
$str = "txt,csv"
create-filter $str
*.txt
*.csv
$filter = create-filter $str
Get-ChildItem . -Include $filter -Recurse
    Directory: C:\temp\test1


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         6/8/2019  10:47 AM             68 -44.csv
-a----         6/8/2019  10:47 AM            101 -54.csv
-a----        6/11/2019   8:50 AM            229 count.txt
-a----        6/11/2019   8:58 AM            170 destination.txt
-a----        6/11/2019   8:53 AM            302 f.txt
-a----        6/12/2019   6:36 AM            294 hashash.txt
-a----         6/6/2019   1:14 PM              4 jaf.csv
-a----         6/6/2019   1:31 PM              0 job1.txt
```

Comment: I have done what you suggested. Now my Create-Filter function is the same as yours. If I pass as argument a string containing "csproj, vbproj, sln", after returning from function, $filter variable contains *.csproj *.vbproj *.sln (separated by white spaces), so Get-ChildItem is returning nothing...

Comment: I always pass a string such as  "csproj, vbproj, sln" to $filter parameter in Create-filter.

Comment: Is this actually Powershell v2?

Comment: My changes work for me even on v2. Do not surround the variable passed into -Include with quotes. Quotes just tell PowerShell to turn something into a string. Write-Host has the same effect

Comment: My powershell version is 5.1.17763.316 (I have updated my post, see image). I do not surround the variable passed into -Include. I call the Create-Filter function and I assign the value returned into a variable: $filter = Create-Filter($str) and then I pass $filter to -Include. Please, update your post and show an example on how you call the function Create-Filter and how you pass the value returned into -Include.

Comment: Ok, finally I have solved it. Your solution works. The problem was that I was assigning the value returned by Create-Filter function into the same variable as that I was passing as argument (see my post updated). But what's the difference? In other languages such as C# you can do it, that is, assigning the returned value of a function to the same variable you pass as argument. Out of curiosity, why is it not working in powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I would use -filter which is faster.

```
ls -r D:\Path\To\My\Root\Folder -filter *.csproj,*.vbproj,*.sln
```

EDIT:  Aww, that doesn't work.  But this does.  I'm not sure what you need the function for.

```
ls -r D:\Path\To\My\Root\Folder -include *.csproj,*.vbproj,*.sln
```

or

```
$source = 'D:\Path\To\My\Root\Folder'
$filter = '*.csproj','*.vbproj.*','*.sln' # or
$filter = echo *.csproj,*.vbproj,*.sln 

ls -r $source -include $filter
```

Comment: I need a function that once I pass a string such as "csproj, vbproj, sln" it should return *.csproj, *.vbproj, *.sln (comma-separated) that then I can pass it into -Include parameter.