# Using the same variable as parameter and storage when calling a function in powershell

Tags: function, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, get-childitem

Recently I had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56621552/passing-powershell-get-childitem-filter-parameter-through-a-string-variable-is-n) problem. After investigating a lot of hours, finally I discovered that the problem was in using the same variable for:

- Storing the value returned by the function
- Pass it as a parameter to the function

So taken into account below function:

```
Function Create-Filter($filter)
{    
    $filter.Split(',') | ForEach-Object {"*.$($_.Trim())"}
    return
}
```

(Above function gets a string variable such as "csproj, vbproj" and converts it into *.csproj *.vbproj)

...below code is not working, variable $filter used for -Include parameter does not like to Get-ChildItem and it is returning nothing:

```
$filter = "csproj, vbproj"
$filter = Create-Filter ($filter)
Get-ChildItem "D:\Path\To\My\Root\Folder" -Include $filter -Recurse
```

Instead below one is working by using a different variable for storing and pass it as a parameter:

```
$filter = "csproj, vbproj"  
$formattedfilter = Create-Filter ($filter)
Get-ChildItem "D:\Path\To\My\Root\Folder" -Include $formattedfilter -Recurse
```

... now Get-ChildItem works.

In other languages one can use the same variable for passing it as a parameter and storing the value returned by the function. So could you explain me why in powershell this does not work if one uses the same variable?

Comment: your code produces >>> `Get-ChildItem 'D:\Path\To\My\Root\Folder' -Include *.csproj *.vbproj -Recurse` <<< on  my system. i STRONGLY recommend you remove the parens around the `Create-Filter` input ... that is known to cause odd problems since a PoSh function is NOT supposed to be called with the parameter values in parens.

Comment: Which PowerShell version do you use? I'm unable to reproduce on 5.1 and 6.2 (the only ones I have on hand right now).

Comment: I cannot reproduce on 5.1, 4.0, and 2.0. I think calling `Create-Filter $Filter` is the thing to try without parentheses.

Comment: It is behaving as if the first assignment of `$filter` is permanently giving it a string type. So the reassignment is just converting the array output into a string (space delimited).

Comment: @robdy I use v5.1.17763.316

Comment: As @Lee_Dailey says, it is recommended to not use parentheses in powershell when calling functions. Here is a good post about it: https://serverfault.com/questions/819763/why-is-it-wrong-to-call-functions-with-parentheses-in-powershell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why your code won't work, as the return in your case is redundant and the result is put on the output stream.

So the same code but refactored:

```
function New-Filter
{    
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String[]] $filter
    )

    return $filter.Split(',') | ForEach-Object {"*.$($_.Trim())"}
}

$filter = @("csproj, vbproj")
$filter = New-Filter $filter
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\Path\To\My\Root\Folder" -Include $filter -Recurse
```